# React Native How to redirect on page when click on notification

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I’m using react-native-push-notification on a page with a [timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onTfd.png). If the application is in the background after 5 minutes, I’m notified that time has passed. When I click on the notification, it goes to this page. But when I close the application completely and after 5 minutes I click on the notification, it goes to the start page. Now the question is how to make it go to this page?

```
//
let remainingTime = (this.state.minute * 60 + this.state.seconds) * 1000;

let date = new Date(Date.now() + remainingTime);
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    message: "Message",
    date,
    soundName: "rush"
});
```

Comment: When you ask the question here then you have to provide some snippets of your code. So can others will get idea and give the solution.

Answer (score 1):

When any notification is opened or received the callback **`onNotification`** is called passing an object with the notification data.

**Notification** object example:

```
{
    foreground: false, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was received in foreground or not
    userInteraction: false, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was opened by the user from the notification area or not
    message: 'My Notification Message', // STRING: The notification message
    data: {}, // OBJECT: The push data
}
```

So when onNotification is triggered you can get **data object** and based on its value you can write your logic of redirection.

To be more clear you can have this code on your start screen or main file

```
var PushNotification = require('react-native-push-notification');

PushNotification.configure({

    // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
    onRegister: function(token) {
        console.log( 'TOKEN:', token );
    },

    // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
    onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );

        // process the notification
   }
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me...I tried this in componentDidMount method in my home screen but nothing comes up in the console.

Comment: Can you help? @Firu

Comment: without any code, I am sorry I can't help, moreover onNotification is called by the library itself, so if its not  happening check their github issues page