# How to check if the app is opened by clicking the app icon or by clicking on the notification in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react-native to build the app. I need to navigate to two different routes depending on how the app is being opened. Is there a way that I could differentiate it?

Comment: You can use this refrence ---->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337117/detect-whether-react-native-ios-app-was-opened-via-push-notification

Comment: I have to get a solution in android too. Could  you please help me with that

Comment: This will solve you issue --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879364/react-native-how-to-redirect-on-page-when-click-on-notification